# Why am I getting a strange number in this code?

Tags: c, factorial

I want to write a C program that evaluates the factorials of the integers from 1 to 5 and print them in a tabular format. However, I keep getting a strange number over everything. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int factorial;

    printf("X\t Factorial of X\n");

    for(int x=1; x<=5; x++)
    {
        factorial = 1;
        for (int j=1; j<=x; j++)
        {
            factorial *=j;
        }
        printf("%d\t %d\n", &x, &factorial);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here's the result of this code:

```
X        Factorial of X
6356768  6356772
6356768  6356772
6356768  6356772
6356768  6356772
6356768  6356772
```

What's wrong with my code? The result should be like this:

```
X       Factorial of X
1       1
2       2
3       6
4       24
5       120
```

Comment: Remove the `&`.

Comment: Please turn on the warnings in your compiler. A modern compiler should give you some hint if you provide a parameter with a type that does not match the format specifier.

Comment: @Gerhardh i'm using C-free 5.0 lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `&` which stands for address of. You are printing address of the variable, not its value.

```
    printf("%d\t %d\n", x, factorial);
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `printf` (and related **output** functions), the `%d` format specifier expects an `int` as the corresponding argument. In your `printf("%d\t %d\n", &x, &factorial);` you are passing the *addresses* of the `x` and `factorial` variables.

So, just remove the two `&` (address of) operators: `printf("%d\t %d\n", x, factorial);`!

*You are possibly being confused by the fact that, for `scanf` (and other **input** functions), the `%d` specifier requires a pointer to its target variable.*

Answer (score 0):

printf("%d\t %d\n", &x, &factorial);
&x and &factorial are addresses of those variables, not the variables themself. Omit the &.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike `scanf`, `printf()` with format `%d` requires *integer values*, not addresses (`&x` is the address containing an integer, so a pointer to integer which type is `int *`). The correct expression is

```
printf("%d\t %d\n", x, factorial);
```

---

### Why was the previous expression wrong?

With `printf("%d\t %d\n", &x, &factorial);` you are asking to printf to print the decimal representations of the addresses of `x` and `factorial` respectively.

For this reason it is not surprising that the values that used to be printed, `6356768` and `6356772`:

1. Are big numbers, multiples of 4 (because they address integers, that have a size 4 bytes, and in 32 bits architectures like yours are aligned to memory locations multiples of 4)
2. They are memory locations, and their addresses do not vary even if their contents are changed

---

You can find `printf` documentation [here](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf).

Answer (score 0):

In the statement printf("%d\t %d\n", &x, &factorial); you have used '&' which prints the address of that element.