# My array isn't printing the actual values

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I have a simple program that is supposed to ask the user for 10 integers and print them out, but instead of printing the integer it prints a random 7 digit number that increases by 4 for every new int.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int number = 0;
    int numbers[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("Please enter 10 numbers: ");
        scanf_s("%d", &number);
        numbers[i] = &number;

        printf("Your number was %d\n", &numbers[i]);

    }

}
```

And the program ends up doing something like:

```
Please enter 10 numbers: 1

Your number was 5241560

Please enter 10 numbers: 2

Your number was 5241564

Please enter 10 numbers: 3

Your number was 5241568
```

And so on, with a different 7 digit number every time, but always increasing by 4.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I getting a strange number in this code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61460871/why-am-i-getting-a-strange-number-in-this-code) It seems to be a common mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The numbers that you might think of as random in this case are not random after all! They're actually addresses of the array elements. Why?
Well because in your printf you print out `&numbers[i]`. Putting the '&' sign means accessing the address of certain value, as opposed to accessing the value itself.
Therefore if you're interested in printing array elements as opposed to *addresses* of array elements then you should remove '&' form your printf statement.

Also `numbers[i] = &number;` means "assign address of variable `number` to ith element of array. You should remove unnecessary '&' signs if accessing addresses is not what you actually want.

Here are some good references on addresses in C:
[Pointers in C](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointers.htm),
[5 Minute guide to C pointers](https://denniskubes.com/2017/01/24/the-5-minute-guide-to-c-pointers/)

Answer (score 0):

You use `&` unnecessarily.  Replace

```
 numbers[i] = &number;
```

with

```
numbers[i] = number;
```

and

```
printf("Your number was %d\n", &numbers[i]);
```

with

```
printf("Your number was %d\n", numbers[i]);
```

You also don't use `int argc, char *argv[]` parameters so replace

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

with

```
int main(void)
```